# Restore backup after upgrade to Juno

Tags: release-juno

Until now I've used Elementary 0.4.1 Loki. Now I've installed the Juno version. Before that I've made a backup of 0.4.1 with Timeshift,and restored it in 5.0 but none of the software appears. Is it possible to restore a 0.4.1(Loki) backup in version 5 (Juno)?